# Great classic Shadowrun adventures/campaigns?

Tags: shadowrun

Which Shadowrun adventures and campaigns are generally considered noteworthy, in that they're respective classics, really defined or redefined the setting, or widely considered great or brilliant for some other reason?

When I ask this question about, for example, Warhammer FRP, the unavoidable answer is *The Enemy Within*, which defined and fleshed out a lot of the setting and the genre, *Shadows over Bogenhafen* which set the tone and theme for a lot of later adventures, perhaps *Death on the Reik* for its sprawling, open-ended structure visiting (and thereby defining) a lot of the countryside, and *Power Behind the Throne* for being this crazy complex ultimate social intrigue adventure. For Earthdawn, I believe the *Prelude to War* campaign is considered a quality campaign dealing with important events defining the tensions in the setting (its sequel was considered less good; I'm totally unaware of anything beyond that).

For Shadowrun, I suspect there have been a lot more adventures than for WFRP or Earthdawn, but I'm totally unfamiliar with most of them. Do any of them stand out? Did any truly define what Shadowrun was really about? Which ones have, over the years, been considered the most important, most popular, best, most defining or otherwise outstanding adventures and campaigns?

I'm *not* looking for a single answer, a specific "winner", or for a discussion on the relative merits of one versus another, but for a reference to all adventures and campaigns that are worth checking out for any new Shadowrun GM looking into classic stuff. There are no doubt many adventures and campaigns that stand out for one reason or another, that had an impact on the players, the fans, the community, but I wasn't around at the time and missed out. I'm interested in on overview of *all* adventures and campaigns that have made a mark on Shadowrun history.

Comment: Hi and welcome, "What is better" is off topic pretty much universally on Stack Exchange sites, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/ has a pretty good explanation as to why.

Comment: For this sort of thing, you really want a forum site. Try [RPG.net](http://forum.rpg.net) or [Reddit's /r/RPG](http://www.reddit.com/r/rpg).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13241/discussion-between-ze-demon-pyro-and-mcv)

Comment: Please do not argue in comments. As it stands, this question will remain closed until it can have a single correct answer.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton I think this question can already have a single correct answer: a list of noteworthy Shadowrun adventures with a short explanation what makes each one special. If this is not enough, I'd like to know how to improve my question in order to get this kind of answer.

Comment: @mcv be aware that ~10 or so edits will trip your question into community wiki. You could ask us on meta about how to ask this question well, or something!

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Thanks, I didn't know that. But would that be a bad thing?

Comment: @mcv Community wiki means you won't earn rep for upvotes, so that depends. (Most tend to agree that upvotes _are pretty nice_, too)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs At the moment I'm just happy to get an answer at all.

Comment: @mcv I suggest you ask Meta how a question like this can be made to work, then.

Comment: Everyone has a different view of what makes something "great" or "classic" or "impactful." SE isn't designed to handle citizens competing to defend their definitions of such things. You might be more successful asking for references to existing articles on the topic, because that's a question about resources and references--a big difference from asking us to write the articles ourselves, which is what your question is currently doing. I do suggest that you make a meta post about it, though, because that provides a thread to which the community can refer in the future.

Comment: @BESW Why would it be about competing definition? It's possible to add answers even after an answer has been upvoted or accepted, because different viewpoints can add value. And how much a particular campaign is sold or discussed are measurable things. But I don't want to restrict answers to any particular measurement; I want to trust the opinions of experts exactly because they are experts. People who are better grounded in Shadowrun than I, know better what makes one adventure better, more classic or impactful than another. I'll make that meta thread, though.

Comment: Despite being closed, this question now got me a "Notable Question" badge. It does sound like there's a demand for answers to this sort of question.